# Snc_redis exception when loading

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, redis, symfony-2.3

I'm getting the following exception:

```
InvalidConfigurationException: The child node "clients" at path "snc_redis" must be configured.
```

I use Symfony 2.3 SncRedisBundle 1.1.x-dev

In config.yml I have

```
  clients:
      default:
          type: predis
          alias: default
          dsn: redis://localhost
          logging: %kernel.debug%
```

And I've followed the [docs here](https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) for installation...

Any idea what would cause this ?

Answer (score 0):

The bundle is looking for configuration values under `snc_redis` root (as you can see [here](https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration/Configuration.php#L40)), which you did not provide.

Now, all this wouldn't normally be a problem, but the `clients` child node is mandatory (as you can see [here](https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration/Configuration.php#L86)), which causes the error above.

Simply make the root configuration node in your `config.yml` to be `snc_redis` and the problem will go away. You probably simply missed it when doing copy-paste.